# White image while inserting a SVG image in TCPDF

Tags: pdf, svg, tcpdf

I'm trying to insert some SVG images in a PDF using TCPDF with the method TCPDF::ImageSVG, but when I try this I get a white space.
If I try to enable TCPDF::setRasterizeVectorImages the image shows in the PDF file, but it is rasterized of course and so its quality is not good.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TCPDF's SVG handling is quite limited, and the cause of your issue depends on the SVG you are trying to use.  Later versions of TCPDF support more SVG functionality, so if you haven't done so, try using a later version of TCPDF.

If an update doesn't resolve the issue, and you're forced to use raster images, you can improve quality at the cost of file size. You can do this by rasterizing them at a high DPI yourself outside of TCPDF. Once you've done this, take your new high-resolution raster image and add it to your PDF with the `Image` method like any other raster image.  At work we usually rasterize to 300dpi, but your application may call for more or less.

If your image gets added to the PDF far larger on the page than you expected, specify at least one of the dimensions so TCPDF knows how much of the page you're intending the image to use.